# C Programming EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code:1 ,address=0x0) Error

Tags: c, linked-list

Hi guys I'm learning C programming. I wanted to write some codes for learning linked list topic but there is a problem. This code about creating linked list with 5 nodes, writing something into 3rd node, printing them to console.

Here is all of my codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

struct node{    
     char *data;
     struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;
node *root;


void nodeAdd(node *n, int x)
{    
  node *iter;
  iter=root;

  for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
  {
    iter->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    iter->next->data="0";
    iter->next->next=NULL;

    iter=iter->next;
    printf("Node created.\n");
  }
}

void nodeWrite(node *n,char *string,int x)
{
  node *temp;
  temp=root;

  for(int k=0;k<x;k++)
  {
    temp=temp->next;
  }
  strcpy(temp->data,string);  //HERE IS ERROR
  printf("\n");
  printf("%s \n",temp->data);
  printf("Node writed.");
} 

void nodePrint(node *n)
{
  while(root->next!=NULL)
    printf("%s\n",root->data);
  root=root->next;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  root = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

  nodeAdd(root,5);
  nodeWrite(root,"WTF", 3);
  nodePrint(root);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please always apply proper indentation to your code. Then it will be more visible that your `while` loop in `nodePrint` will loop forever.

Comment: Not directly related: `void nodeWrite(node *n,char *string,int x){ ..` is weird, you don't use the `n` parameter but you use directly the global variable `root`.

Comment: All your function have parameter `n` but don't use it as they directly manipulate `root`. Is this intentional?

Comment: Thanks for your advice guys, as I told before I'm not really good at coding and I'm trying to learning someting and gaining experience about it. Thanks again. @Gerhardh

Comment: @MichaelWalz It is working but not useful understood. Thank you so much.

Comment: @TarkanBatar there is a huge difference between "it is working" and "the program is properly written and it is working"

Comment: @TarkanBatar Especially when your are new and unexperienced with C, indentation is important. It provides hints about the structure. But be aware that indentation does not affect the code.

Comment: It seems agressive attitude on my comment but it is just about my bad English skills so sorry. I used "understood" means "I understand it.". Forgive me :) @MichaelWalz

Comment: @TarkanBatar no problem.I just wanted to point out that a poorly written program can still work correctly and do what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is an unintialized pointer variable. Initialize with the address of a valid memory that you allocate. That will solve the problem. Now you have udnefined behavior.

What you can possibly do is

1. Use `char array` instead of using pointer.
2. Allocate dynamically the memory.

In case of 1.

```
struct node{

     char data[MAXSTRINGLEN];
     struct node *next;
};
```

In case of 2:

Initially make the pointers point to `NULL`. So now you can allocate to it like this

```
temp->data = malloc(sizeof *temp->data*MAXSTRINGLEN);
if( temp->data == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in malloc");
    exit(1);
}
```

Just one point, free the allocated memory when you are done working with it.

Use of the global variable here is not really required here. You can always pass return pointers from memory and assign it to the `struct node*`. Or yes you can use double pointers. Use of global variable is not needed here.

Clean up code, that are redundant and not required. That makes things readable and less confusing.

Comment: I did it and it is working now, thank you so much @coderredoc

Answer (score 2):

The program initially is designed incorrectly and has undefined behavior..

For example the data member `data` of the node `root` was not initialized. So its output in the function `nodePrint` results in undefined behavior. Moreover the function itself is incorrect.

Neither function uses its parameter `node *n`.

In this statement

```
strcpy(temp->data,string);
```

there is an attempt to change the string literal pointed to by the data member temp->data provided that the data member was initialized (as it was pointed above the data member is not initialized for the node `root`). You may not change a string literal. Any attempt to modify a string literal leads to undefined behavior.

There is no need to declare the node `root` as a global variable.

Parameters of the function `main` are not used in the program. So the function should be declared like

```
int main( void )
```